# Convergence of functions in $L^1$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, convergence-divergence, lebesgue-integral

I am trying to prove a theorem, and I have been able to reduce it to the following question. I feel that this should be easy, but I can't see the solution.

If $(g_n)_{n\geq 1}$ is a sequence of functions in $L^1$ such that $\lim_{n\to\infty} \|g_n\|_1 = 0$, then there exists an $N$ such that $g_N$ is in $L^2$. Here, $\|\cdot\|_1$ is the norm in $L^1$.

I am not even sure this is true, but any help would be appreciated.

Comment: In what spaces are you working? This is important since, for example, your assertion is trivially true in $\mathbb{N}$ with counting measure (in this case $L^1 \subset L^2$), however it is false in $\mathbb{R}^n$ with Lebesgue measure.

Comment: A counterexample in $[0,1]$ with Lebesgue measure would be something like $f_n = \frac{1}{n\sqrt{x}}$

Comment: @DevenWare You could post your comment as an answer.

Comment: @DavideGiraudo Okay, done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The claim is actually false in $[0,1]$ with Lebesgue measure.

A counterexample can be seen by consider the functions $f_n = \frac{1}{n\sqrt{x}}$, then the integral is $\frac{2}{n}$ so each are in $L^1$ and $\left|\left|f_n\right|\right|_1 \rightarrow 0$.

However, for all $n$ we have $f_n^2 = \frac{1}{n^2x}$, so $f_n \notin L^2$ for any $n$.